# Not able to be notified when casting menu item is clicked using Cast Companion Library

Tags: android, castcompanionlibrary

I'm using Cast Companion Library version 2.7.0, I'll update soon to the latest (2.7.4) ;)
My problem is I am not able to be notified when casting menu item is clicked.

My code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
mediaRouteMenuItem = castManager.addMediaRouterButton(menu, R.id.media_route_menu_item);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
if(item.getItemId() == R.id.media_route_menu_item) {
Log.d(TAG, "[ onOptionsItemSelected ] Chromecast connect action");
return true;
}
return super.onOptiotemSelected(item);
}
```

I've tested to add a MenuItemClickListener too, but no luck

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
mediaRouteMenuItem = castManager.addMediaRouterButton(menu, R.id.media_route_menu_item);
mediaRouteMenuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
Log.d(TAG, "[ onMenuItemClicked ] Chromecast connect");
return true;
}
});
return true;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to be notified?

Comment: Because I want to track the use of this feature with analytics

Comment: You currently cannot do that unless you implement your own MediaRouteDialogFactory.

Comment: Any update regarding this Mr @AliNaddaf ?